# A ggmap too small when rendered within a Rmd file?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, ggmap

I generate a ggmap plot that when executed from the r script looks perfect; however, the same plot in a Rmd file looks too small with half the width and disproportionate w.r.t the points being plotted.

What setting would help making the ggmap plot to take as much space as possible? My plotting code looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

ggmap(map) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = colorSpec) +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=lon, y=lat, colour=Technology, size=score), 
             position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0.01, jitter.height=0.01, seed=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=6), legend.title = element_blank())
```

This is the correct expected output when plotted from the r script:

[image]

And this is the smaller and disproportionate output when plotted from the rmd and generated PDF file:

[image]

Comment: Your 'correct' output has a legend on the right side.  Your 'disproportionate' output and your code position the legend on the bottom.  Which do you want?  Removing the `theme(legend.position = ...` might help.

Comment: @mrhellmann good point, I tried both ways and still shows very small.

Comment: have you set fig.width and/or fig.height in the code chunk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes not from `ggplot`, but from the markdown settings (e.g. figure margins).
You can try by specifying the `plotting area` when calling the ggplot block in the markdown.

````
# using knitr::spin()
#+ out.width = "100%", fig.align = "center", echo=FALSE

# using Rmarkdwon
```{r, out.width = "100%", fig.align = "center", echo=FALSE}
   your ggplot code
```
# or

```{r, fig.width=10, fig.height=2, fig.fullwidth=TRUE}
    your ggplot code
```
````

You can also try to increase the overall width of the page with `options(width="a high value here")`

Note that if you are using a template, all the above options will fail as you need to modify the template css file. If you cannot do that, then you may want to consider saving the ggplot as image and import it in your document.

For the people wondering about `knitr::spin()`, I suggest to spend some time reading about it ([here](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/render-reports-directly-from-R-scripts/) or [here](https://rpubs.com/alobo/spintutorial).

Comment: What is the `# using spin` line as well as the `#+...` line ?

Comment: `knitr` has the `spin()` function, that allows you to render markdowns directly in `.R` files. I find it much more usable that `Rmarkdown`. Have a look at an example here  (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-spin.R)

Comment: Thank you! the second (not the first) variant worked! `fig.width=10, fig.height=10, fig.fullwidth=TRUE, echo=FALSE,message=FALSE`

Comment: @fra Thanks, I will check it out.